# Stack size dimension ocupied by recursive function

Tags: c++

For a C++ program that is using a recursive function, how can I evaluate the dynamic stack size occupied by this function?

Comment: How many times does this function recur?

Comment: @delnan If the exact number of bytes: then that's 42.

Comment: Completely dependent on Hardware/OS/Compiler/Optimization Level. Thus nearly imposable to answer. And meaningless. Why do you care. If there is even a potential of blowing your stack then you should be using an iterative solution.

Answer (score 7):

```
void recursive_function()
{
  int dummy;
  cout << "stack = " << &dummy << '\n';
  ...
}
```

Watch the value of `&dummy` rise as the stack usage goes up (or fall if your stack grows downwards).

Comment: Or jumps around memory if you use a non linear stack.

Comment: OK, well at least the OP would know what kind of stack they had.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

ssize_t recurse(int limit, char* stack = NULL)
{
    char dummy;

    if (stack == NULL)
        stack = &dummy;

    if (limit > 0)
        return recurse(limit - 1, stack);
    else
        return stack - &dummy;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int limit = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("depth %d took %zd bytes\n", limit, recurse(limit));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If I run this with `4` I get:

```
depth 4 took 192 bytes
```

As others have suggested in comments, this is not completely portable, but it should work on a fairly wide variety of current systems.  Note that the result type is signed in case something "weird" happens--you can surely check it for sanity (say, make sure it's between 5 and 500, depending on what else your function contains).